# How can I find out what solution(s) interact with an entity?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

How can I find out what solution(s) "interact" with an entity?

e.g. which solution creates a custom entity, which solution or solutions add fields to a standard entity, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this for unmanaged solutions, and there is no UI for doing this in managed solutions.  For managed solutions you could download the solution and search through the xml to see what it's definitions are for the entities that you're concerned about.

Comment: Ouch, searching through loads of XML ... oh, the joy  :-)

Comment: You can use the CRM Solution Extractor to simplify what you're searching through... And just to reiterate, this is only valid for Managed Solutions.  Exporting the unmanaged solution will just contain everything that is in the Org, not just what it did...

Comment: @Darryl What's the CRM Solution Extractor? ... done a search and not getting any significant hits?   Are you referring to the Solution Packager?